# Checking spelling of text file and keep count of mispelled words (C++)

Tags: c++, hashtable

The prompt is to keep track of mispelled words in a text file using the provided dictionary. The only rule is to match the words in the text file to dictionary. Not worrying about uppercase/lowercase, punctuation or quotes. I was told that I could use a hash table but I really don't know where to start because I just started coding couple of months ago. Can I get some help? This is what I have so far and I know it's not much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>



using namespace std;


//takes files name and spell checks it
void spelling (string file)
{
    string words;
    ifstream reading;
    ifstream dictionary;

    reading.open("reading.txt");
    dictionary.open("dictionary.txt");


}

// Turn words into hash codes
int hash_code(const string& str)
{
    int h = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        h = 31 * h + str[i];
    }
    return h;
}




int main ()
{
    string file;
    string word;
    string reading;
    cout<<"Enter the spell check file name"<<endl;
    cin >> reading;

    if (reading == "flatland.txt") {
        spelling(file);
    }
    else {
        cout<<"That is not the correct file name. Enter again.";
        cin>>reading;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You will learn much more by trying to use proper libraries instead of writing a lot of code yourself. Use Boost.Tokenizer to divide the text in words and the use the Hunspell  library to check for misspelled words (and even give suggestions for word replacements).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a starting point. Go read up on [unordered set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <unordered_set>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in{"dictionary.txt"};

    std::unordered_set<std::string> words;
    std::string w;
    while (in >> w)
        words.insert(w);

    for (auto str : words)
        std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

This should read all the words in your dictionary and print them again, so you can double check that the reading worked. Caveat: I am assuming that the dictionary file just lists words separated by whitespace.

Once this works you will have your dictionary in an unordered set where you can do lookup. Then all you have to do is read your text one word at a time, check if the dictionary contains that word, and report if it doesn't - simple. :)

Then, of course, you will find that this isn't exactly right, but then you can try to improve it. Remember to test often, to check if your code actually does what you expect - a common beginner error is to write tons of code and only run it once you are "done". Write a bit, test that it works, fix it if it doesn't, and only move on to the next bit once the first actually works.

Good luck and have fun.